# Displaying all the values in Run key

Tags: python, windows, registry, winreg

I am very new to python programming and I am kind of lost here, I really appreciate it if I can get some help with this code.

So I am trying to only list all the values in the Run key. This is to find out what programs run when the computer starts...

I get together this code but I don't know how to make it list all the values.

Note: In the query value ex instead of 3 dots there should be something, but I don't know what to put to make it show all the values.

Please help I'm clueless.

```
from _winreg import *
aReg = ConnectRegistry(None,HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
aKey = OpenKey(aReg, r"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run")
for i in range(1024):
    try:
        subkey_name=EnumKey(aKey,i)
        subkey=OpenKey(aKey,subkey_name)
        val=QueryValueEx(subkey, "...")
        print val
    except WindowsError:
        break
```